# How do you create a mailto: link without the (to) part

Tags: uri, mailto

How do you properly construct a mailto: link without the part.
`mailto:someaddress@example.com?`
I dont want the address and just want whats in the parameters afterward to be filled in through the mailto.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Yes you can

```
mailto:?body=tisbody&subject=thisbethesubject
```

Answer (score 6):

Did you mean

```
<a href="mailto:"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=yoursubjecthere&amp;body=yourbodyhere">Share using Email</a>
```

Answer (score -14):

You can use mailto in this way

```
<a href="mailto:user@user.com?subject=Subject&amp;cc=CC&amp;bcc=BCC&amp;body=BODY">Clickme!</a>
```

Comment: The question specifically asked for it without the address, and that HTML is invalid.

Comment: They only "invalid" part of the HTML is that your `&` should be `&amp;` although Mr. Dorward is right in saying you didn't actually answer the question posed.